# put another thread in sleep

Tags: c++, multithreading

i have a vector of objects std::vector and the fo object has a method start() where i create the thread specific to this object and now depends on a variable from this object i want to put it in sleep.
so for example if my object is f1 and the variable is `bool sleep = false;` when the sleep variable is true i want it to go to sleep.

i have tried this method but it doesn't seem to work. i think the if

```
class fo {

public :
    thread* t ;
    bool bedient = false , spazieren = false;
    void start(){
    t =  new thread([this]() {
        while (!this->bedient){
            if (this->spazieren == true){

                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
                this->spazieren = false ;
            }
        }
        this->join();
    });
    }
    void join(){
    t->join(); delete t;
    }
};
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, but if you ask what the title says then you can't do it with the standard.

Comment: If you ever need to put something "to sleep", you are likely *doing it wrong*. You may want to re-visit your code design.

Comment: You likely want a conditional variable, not a sleep bool hack thing.

Comment: Before I write up an answer... my usual questions: **What are you really trying to do?**  As others have suggested, asking another thread "to sleep" is an indicator of something that is not the correct design.  But perhaps what you really meant is that you want the thread **to wait** on something before continuing.  There's all kinds of good patterns for that.  Elaborate, and you will get better advice.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis i have a server thread and cafe clients threads i want to be able to put the clients to sleep using a status variable if the queue is longer than a specific size (i know it's a kind of busy waiting)

Comment: @JesperJuhl and selbie i know that it would be better if i use cv or semaphores but this is what i want to implement

Comment: You got some answers, but you did not respond. If the answers are helped you, please upvote. If the answer is a solution for your problem and correct, please accept the answer. If you need to know some more details, write a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You have "generated" a lot of problems on your code:

1)
Setting any kind of variable in one thread is potentially invisible in any other thread. If you want to make the other threads sees you changes in the first thread, you have to synchronize your memory. That can be done by using `std::mutex` with lock and unlock around every change of data or using `std::atomic` variables, which do the sync themselves or a lot of other methods. Please read a book about multi threaded programming!

2)
You try to join your own thread. That is not the correct usage at all. Any thread can join on others execution end but not on itself. That makes no sense!

3)
If you do not set manually the "sleep" var, your thread is running a loop and is simply doing nothing. A good method to heat up your core and the planet ;)

```
class fo {

    public :
        std::thread* t=nullptr ; // prevent corrupt delete if no start() called!
        std::atomic<bool> bedient = false ;
        std::atomic<bool> spazieren = false;
        void start()
        {
            t =  new std::thread([this]()
                                 {
                                     while (!this->bedient)
                                     {
                                         if (this->spazieren == true)
                                         {
                                             std::cout << "We are going to sleep" << std::endl;

                                             std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
                                             this->spazieren = false ;
                                         }
                                     }
                                     std::cout << "End loop" << std::endl;
                                 });
        }

        ~fo() { delete t; }

        void join()
        {
            std::cout << "wait for thread ends" << std::endl;

            t->join();
        }
};


int main()
{
    fo f1;
    f1.start();
    sleep(1);
    f1.spazieren = true;
    sleep(1);
    f1.bedient = true;


    f1.join();
}
```

BTW:

1. Please do not use `using namespace std`!
2. Your design seems to be problematic. Setting vars from external threads to control execution of a thread is typically an abuse. You should think again for your design!
3. Manually using new/delete can be result in memory leaks.
4. Creating something with a start() method which later on will be deleted is mysterious. You should create all objects in the constructor.

Comment: I can imagine the `start()` method, lurking in the shadows, wearing an overcoat and a big hat. When I aproach, it mumbles: "are you feeling lucky, boy?" +1

Answer (score 0):

I would try refactoring your code to use std::future instead of std::thread, furthermore there are a few issues which I believe you'll run into in the short term.

1. You shouldn't try to join while in the thread you're joining. That is, the code as you have it will never terminate. The lambda you've defined will attempt to call join, however, the lambda will never return since it's waiting on join which will only itself return when the lambda does so. In other words, you're telling it to wait on itself.

   2. You're revealing too much information about the functionality of your class to the outside world. I would suggest moving implementation details into a .cc rather than putting it in the class declaration. Short of that, however, you're providing immediate access to your control variables spazieren and bedient. This is a problem because it complicates control flow and makes for weak abstraction.
   3. Your bools are not atomic. If you attempt to modify them from outside the thread they're being read you'll run into crashes. And in some environments these crashes might be sporadic and very hard to debug.
   4. Only sleeping when asked can be useful if you absolutely need to finish a task as soon as possible, but be aware that it's going to max out a core and if deployed to the wrong environment can cause major problems and slowdowns. I don't know what the end goal is for this program, but I would suggest considering changing the yield in the following code example to -some- period of time to sleep, 10 ms should be sufficient to prevent putting too much stress on your cpu.
   5. Your threads status as to whether or not it's actively running is unclear with your implementation. I'd suggest considering an additional bool to indicate if it's running or not so you can more properly decide what to do if start() is called more than once.
   6. When this object destructs it's going to crash if the thread is still running. You need to be sure to join before your destructor finishes running too.

I would consider the following refactorings:

```
#include <memory>
#include <future>
#include <atomic>

class fo 
{
public:
    ~fo()
    {
        this->_bedient = true;
        _workThread.wait();
    }

    void start()
    {
        _workThread = std::async(std::launch::async, [this]() -> bool
            {
                    while(!this->_bedient) 
                    {
                        if(true == this->_spazieren)
                        {

                            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
                            this->_spazieren = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            std::this_thread::yield();
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
            });
    }

    void ShouldSleep(bool shouldSleep)
    {
        this->_spazieren = shouldSleep;
    }

    void ShouldStop(bool shouldStop)
    {
        this->_bedient = !shouldStop;
    }

private:
    std::future<bool> _workThread = {};
    std::atomic<bool> _bedient{ false };
    std::atomic<bool> _spazieren{ false };
};
```